# Java Script Slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow, dreamweaver

I'm following a tutorial to create a slideshow with JavaScript and HTML.

The first image and the "Next" and "Previous" buttons are on the page however when I click on next or previous it says this webpage can not be found. Can someone help me please?

The tutorial can be found [here](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1271798&seqNum=9) and I have also included the HTML and JavaScript code below.

The html code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0
    Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/
            xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
     <title>Image Slideshow</title>
     <script type="text/javascript"
         src="script09.js"></script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
     <div align="center">
        <h1>Welcome, Robot Overlords!</h1>
        <img src="images/robot1.jpg"
            id="myPicture" width="200"
            height="400" alt="Slideshow" />
        <h2><a href="previous.html"
            id="prevLink">&lt;&lt;
            Previous</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a
            href="next.html" id="nextLink">Next
            &gt;&gt;</a></h2>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and The JavaScript code is

```
window.onload = initLinks;

var myPix = new Array("images/robot1.jpg",
    "images/robot2.jpg","images/robot3.jpg");
var thisPic = 0;

function initLinks() {
     document.getElementById("prevLink").
         onclick = processPrevious;
     document.getElementById("nextLink").
         onclick = processNext;
 }

function processPrevious() {
     if (thisPic == 0) {
        thisPic = myPix.length;
     }
     thisPic--;
     document.getElementById("myPicture").src =
         myPix[thisPic];
     return false;
}

function processNext() {
     thisPic++;
     if (thisPic == myPix.length) {
         thisPic = 0;
     }

     document.getElementById("myPicture").src =
         myPix[thisPic];
     return false;
}
```

Comment: Add the event parameter `e` to the `processPrevious` and `processNext` functions like so: `function processPrevious(e) { ... }` and `function processNext(e) { ... }`. Add this statement as the first statement in each function: `e.preventDefault();`...

Answer (score 0):

Rather than bind your function in a onload init function, try:

```
<a href="previous.html" id="prevLink" onclick="processPrevious();return false;">
```

Chances are your have a js error on the page so the functions are ignored and the a tags just follow the link you have used. Open up the console of your browser and check for syntax errors.

Answer (score 0):

You have given HTML page url in href of both the links.

But I think you just need to change the image src attribute...

Use `href="javascript:"` in both the links. So there is no need of `event.preventDefault()` in this case...

(`href="#"` scrolls the page to the top).... :)